# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when running unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

There are two files in py

```
py/
  bubble.py
  unit.py
```

`unit.py` is:

```
import random
import unittest
from py import bubble

def getl():
    l = []
    for i in range(10):
        l.append(random.randint(1,20))
    return l

class TestBubble(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.l = getl()

    def test_bubble(self):
        sorted_list = sorted(self.l)
        bubble(self.l)
        self.assertListEqual(self.l, sorted_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When running this script i got this:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_bubble (__main__.TestBubble)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit.py", line 27, in test_bubble
    bubble(self.l)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What's the problem with this script?

Comment: you don't have to add `from py import bubble` because they are at the same level. Just use `import bubble`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This the line with the problem:

```
bubble(self.l)
```

`bubble` is a module and you try to call it like a function. For example, you must call `bubble.func(self.l)` where `func` is your function.